Non-additive cohomology theories induced by arbitrary prespectra
Let $F : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbf{Spaces}_{\ast}$ be a function into pointed spaces equipped with a map
$\sigma_n : \Sigma{F_n} \to_{\ast} F_{n+1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We call $\left(F, \sigma\right)$ a prespectrum. One can check that $\left(F, \sigma\right)$ induces a $\mathbb{Z}$-indexed family of contravariant functors $\mathbf{Spaces}_{\ast} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ in the form
$$
\widetilde{F}^n(X) \ := \ \mathrm{colim}_{k \in \omega}\left[ \Sigma^k{X}, F_{n +k} \right]_{\ast}
$$
that satisfies the suspension and exactness axioms of a cohomology theory but maybe not the additivity axiom. Moreover, when $F$ is an $\Omega$-spectrum, in the sense that the adjuncts of $\sigma$ under the suspension-loop adjunction are homotopy equivalences, the family $\widetilde{F}$ reduces to the usual definition of cohomology arising from an $\Omega$-spectrum.
I'm curious, if $F$ is the sphere spectrum (or perhaps any suspension spectrum), then does $\widetilde{F}$ have a "natural" role in any parts of homotopy theory? If $F$ is the fibrant replacement of the sphere spectrum, then it induces stable cohomotopy. In the non-fibrant case, is $\widetilde{F}$ ever called "unstable cohomotopy"? Does it naturally show up in homotopy theory, or do we always want to fibrantly replace it first?

So the formula that you give is already a method to derive the mapping set between a finite CW complex $X$ and a prespectrum $F$ and is essentially the method Adams uses in his "Blue Book". In particular, we don't actually need $F$ to be an $\Omega$-spectrum to get the correct value.

@ConnorMalin Are you referring to Proposition 2.8 in the Blue Book? If so, then the difference in indexing makes me think we want  $F$ to be an $\Omega$-spectrum so that the two colimit formulas align up to a degree shift. What am I missing?

You just are using different gradings.

This is only tangentially related, but if you work with Segal's Gamma space approach to spectra then the inclusion Gamma^op→Set_* is often called the sphere spectrum. It's not, of course, because it's not fibrant in the stable model structure. It's not a "spectrum" at all. But its underlying space is indeed S⁰ and it has the simplicial circle as its delooping. This object is what Connes and Consani call F_1. The homology theory it induces, in the sense of Bousfield and Friedlander, is "the identity," basically.
